# Showing custom loader before data render in WKWebView using swift

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am using WKWebView for content preview & I want to show custom loader before content loading for this I have used below code but not working

```
    class PreviewFileViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {
    var webView: WKWebView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    func getPreviewAccToFileType(fileURL: String){
        webView = WKWebView(frame: otherDocumentView.bounds, configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration())
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        webView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        self.otherDocumentView.addSubview(webView)
        let myURL = URL(string:fileURL)
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.load(myRequest)
    } 

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
      getPreviewAccToFileType(fileURL: "https://api.digiboxx.com/uploads/6216FC50A9594500/1606288259_convert-jpg-to-pdf.net_2020-10-17_10-29-33_3.pdf")

     } 

}

    extension PreviewFileViewController: WKNavigationDelegate {
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didCommit navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        debugPrint("didCommit")
    }
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        debugPrint("didFinish")
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
        debugPrint("didFail")
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

there are different approaches to achieve it
First one is :

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        // webView.isHidden = false
        ActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        print("loaded")
    }
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        
        ActivityIndicator.startAnimating()
        // webView.isHidden = true
        print("loading")
    }
```

Second

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: WKWebView) {
    ActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    
}

func webViewDidStartLoad(webView: WKWebView) {
    ActivityIndicator.startAnimating()
}
```

Third

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    
    if keyPath == "loading"
    {
        ActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }else{
        ActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: what is ActivityIndicator

Comment: Activity indicator is a built in loader for IOS if you want some other indicators have a look at "JGProgressHud" Cocoapod

Comment: yes I need to show custom loader according to file type

Comment: then attach a UIActivityIndicator and try First or second method the loader will work fine